# rest routes deciding update vs add

Tags: rest

I'm writing a web app with node/express and I'm trying to set up some restful routes. Basically I have some generic `items` and I have a page that has a list of these items. so I've set up the following route:

```
router.get('/items')...
```

I'm currently setting up `add/update` items as well, but I'm not sure if I should set up a `PUT` for add and `POST` for update, or use `POST` for both? I've read that `POST` is acceptable for both add/update, but if I use post for add and update, then I have to use the same route, is this correct? Which would mean I have to pass back some sort of 'action' parameter to tell the route what action to take.

is this a situation where I should use `PUT` and `POST` separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use post to do both the insert and update with a url pattern like this

```
POST -> items/  -- add an item
POST -> items/{itemId} -- updates the given item with the id itemId
```

Refer this for a more detailed description

https://stackoverflow.com/a/630475/381407